# C# Make button disabled unless atleast more than 1 items is checked

Tags: c#, validation, checkbox

There is a form with 3 check box items and a button. Unless there are atleast more than 1 items checked on the form keep the button 'Finish' disabled.

```
private void btnFinish_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((checkBlinna.Checked == false && checkSoup.Checked == false) || (checkBlinna.Checked == false && checkGnocchi.Checked == false) || (checkSoup.Checked == false && checkGnocchi.Checked == false))
        {
            btnFinish.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Thought this would work but the button is enabled from the start and when any of the check boxes are checked the button goes disabled forever.

Comment: Just to clarify, "at least more than 1" should probably say "two or more." I learned of this detail when answering and your comment pointed it out.

Answer (score 5):

You can do :

```
void UpdateFinishEnabled()
{
    var boxes = new CheckBox[] { checkBlinna, checkSoup, checkGnocchi };
    btnFinish.Enabled = boxes.Any(b => b.Checked);
}
```

Call inside the form load and the validating handler.

Comment: I liked the Lambda Expression approach. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused with your logic. This should work I think

```
bthFinish.Enabled = checkBlinna.Checked || checkSoup.Checked || checkGnocchi.Checked;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void btnFinish_Validating(...)
```

That's a problem, the Validating event will only be raised when btnFinish loses focus.  Which isn't very appropriate since this code should run when the check box controls change state.  Worse, it will *never* happen when the button is disabled since that prevents it from getting the focus.  Which is why you couldn't make it work.  You'll need to have this code called by *all* of the check box controls' CheckedChanged event handlers.

Just as an alternative, you can also run these kind of state update methods from the Application.Idle event.  Saves you from having to write a bunch of event handling code.  But at a cost of doing some unnecessary work.  Doesn't matter because it is cheap and runs when no other work needs to be done.

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
    }

    void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        bthFinish.Enabled = checkBlinna.Checked || checkSoup.Checked || checkGnocchi.Checked;
    }
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I will take the idea into consideration for my next projects.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a small helper method that you can use to enable/disable the button:

```
private bool AtLeastOneCheck()
{
   return (checkBlinna.Checked || checkSoup.Checked || checkGnocchi.Checked);
}
```

You then call this method whenever you need to enable/disable the button, for example, in the `CheckedChanged` event handler for the checkboxes:

```
btnFinish.Enabled = AtLeastOneCheck();
```

**Edit:** Per your clarification, if you require two or more checked, you can modify the helper method as follows:

```
private int CountChecked()
{
    CheckBox[] AllCheckboxes = { checkBlinna, checkSoup, checkGnocchi };
    return AllCheckboxes.Count(cb => cb.Checked);
}
```

And implement it slightly differently:

```
btnFinish.Enabled = CountChecked() >= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks. Only this is what is more appropriate for my situation:
"Atleast more than 1."

private bool AtLeastOneCheck()
        {
            return (checkBlinna.Checked && checkSoup.Checked || checkBlinna.Checked && checkGnocchi.Checked || checkSoup.Checked && checkGnocchi.Checked);
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnFinish_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{

   btnFinish.Enabled = checkBlinna.Checked || checkSoup.Checked || checkGnocchi.Checked;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I support llia Jerebtsov solution all the way, however my approach would be slightly different I would add and CheckboxChanged event and have all the checkbox tied to the same Event place llia code inside the checkbox event like so:

```
private void CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var boxes = new CheckBox[] { checkBlinna, checkSoup, checkGnocchi };
    btnFinish.Enabled = boxes.Any(b => b.Checked);
}
```

and then it should work hopefully. hope that helped. Credit to llia though :)